# Tokenizing \n and \t characters within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Trying to tokenize sentences in python using nltk except I want to tokenize the \n and \t characters as well.

Example:

In: "This is a\n test"

Out: ['This', 'is', 'a', '\n', 'test']

Is there a way that's directly supported to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

text = "This is a\n test with\talso"
pattern = re.compile('[^\t\n]+|[\t\n]+')

output = [val for values in map(pattern.findall, text.split(' ')) for val in values]
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
['This', 'is', 'a', '\n', 'test', 'with', '\t', 'also']
```

The idea is to first split on a single whitespace then, apply findall for each element in the list resulting from the split. The pattern `[^\t\n]+|[\t\n]+` matches everything that is not a tab or a newline and multiple times and also everything that is a new line or tab multiple times. If you want to consider each tab and newline as a single token change the pattern to:

```
import re

text = "This is a\n test\n\nwith\t\talso"
pattern = re.compile('[^\t\n]+|[\t\n]')
output = [val for values in map(pattern.findall, text.split(' ')) for val in values]
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
['This', 'is', 'a', '\n', 'test', '\n', '\n', 'with', '\t', '\t', 'also']
```